# Global JSON Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, global-variables

If you view the source of what I have so far by clicking on the link below, you'll see the problem I'm having.

- I fetch JSON data from Ricky.json, which contains game data.
- I then try to set the name of Pikachu in the text field with a piece of that JSON data, but instead, it says that it's `undefined`.

My console on Chrome says that the object, "pikachu" exists, because when I alert it in the console, it returns with "Object object". I can also stringify it via the console with JSON.stringify().

Why isn't it global in function `main()` itself, but everywhere else it is???

[Raise a Pikachu](http://nos.heliohost.org/games/RaisePikachu/)

```
function ChangeName(){
    var n=prompt("What would you like to rename your Pikachu?",""+pikachu.pikaname+"");
    pikachu.pikaname=n;
}

function main(){
    try{
        ajaxObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
        pikaname=document.getElementById("pikaname");
        age=document.getElementById("age");pikachu="";
        ajaxObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajaxObj.readyState>=4&&ajaxObj.status==200){
                pikachu=JSON.parse(ajaxObj.responseText);
            }
        }
        ajaxObj.open("GET","players/Ricky.json",true);
        ajaxObj.send();
        pikaname.value=pikachu.pikaname;
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you assign the value in onreadystatechange function? I think the problem is this ajax is asynchroneus and you are trying to set the value before the ajax has returned the json object.

Comment: I was, it's just...It's kinda sloppy in my opinion.

I would really just have everything split into functions, like "SaveGame()", "LoadGame()", "ChangeName()", etc.

Is there any way I can do this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AJAX call runs asynchronously. At the time the line `pikaname.value = pikachu.pikaname;` executes, the JSON is not actually available yet. Instead, you need to set that inside the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
    ajaxObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajaxObj.readyState>=4&&ajaxObj.status==200){
            pikachu=JSON.parse(ajaxObj.responseText);
            // Set the value in the onreadystatechange...
            pikaname.value = pikachu.pikaname;
        }
    }
```

Now, I will also point out that you should probably not be depending on `pikaname` as a global defined without `var`. Instead, define it with `var` outisde any function, or retrieve it and define it with `var` inside the functions that use it.

```
// Define at global scope
var pikachu;
function ChangeName(){
    var n=prompt("What would you like to rename your Pikachu?",""+pikachu.pikaname+"");
    pikachu.pikaname=n;
}

function main(){
    try{
        // Define with var in this function
        var ajaxObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var pikaname=document.getElementById("pikaname");
        var age=document.getElementById("age");
        pikachu="";

        ajaxObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajaxObj.readyState>=4&&ajaxObj.status==200){
                pikachu=JSON.parse(ajaxObj.responseText);
            }
        }
        ajaxObj.open("GET","players/Ricky.json",true);
        ajaxObj.send();
        pikaname.value=pikachu.pikaname;
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would seem to be here:

```
   age=document.getElementById("age");pikachu="";
    ajaxObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajaxObj.readyState>=4&&ajaxObj.status==200){
            pikachu=JSON.parse(ajaxObj.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajaxObj.open("GET","players/Ricky.json",true);
    ajaxObj.send();
    pikaname.value=pikachu.pikaname;
```

The first line assigns an empty string to `pikachu`. (I wouldn't put multiple assignments on a line like that, by the way.)

A few lines later, you're assigning `pikachu` a value again via an asynchronous call.  But it's asynchronous.  So there's no guarantee that assignment will have happened when you get to the last line where you are expecting `pikachu` to be an object with a `pikaname` property.

Chances are at that point either `pikachu` is still an empty string.